# CSV to database table transformation

Tags: database, csv

I have a CSV file and I need to insert the data from CSV to database. The problem is simple, but I want to know still there are any good way to do it. Let me start here with how I am handling it:

1. I have a CSV file. I convert it into a Java collection.
2. I have a mapping xml here. It holds the association between CSV
   column and table column.

For example, my tag in xml is

```
<table name="CustInfo">
  <column srcName="Cust_Name"  tarGetName="CustName"></column>
</table>
```

Now, I will parse the xml and get the `srcName` and it's value from the CSV and make the insert query and thus will insert the data.

Please let me know if you have any approach to work on it.

Comment: Simply your approach and use the first row of the CSV file to indicate the table column name. Lots of loaders out there which can be used to convert such a CSV layout into the correct SQL INSERT statements. Keeping column mappings in a separate XML file just increases complexity and likelyhood of errors

Answer (score 0):

#### Importing CSV with SQLite3

Assuming you've already defined your table, you can import your CSV directly. For example:

```
# Make sure your commands are left-aligned. Spaces before
# dot-commands are a syntax error.
echo '
.mode csv
.import infile.csv your_table' \
| sqlite3 your_database.sqlite3
```

If you're using some other database, the steps are similar, but the specific syntax will obviously be different.